# How to convert string on variable in class?

Tags: python, string

how can i get access to variable in class using string?

```
class GameShop:
    ManaPotion = "ManaPotion"
    priceManaPotion = 50
    HealthPotion = "HealthPotion"
    priceHealthPotion = 50
    StaminaPotion = "StaminaPotion"
    priceStaminaPotion = 50

    itemy = {
        ManaPotion: priceManaPotion,
        HealthPotion: priceHealthPotion,
        StaminaPotion: priceStaminaPotion,

    }

shop = GameShop

print(GameShop.priceHealthPotion)

product_name = input("Product Name")
print(f'{GameShop}' + '.price' + f'{product_name}' )
```

Give result `<class '__main__.GameShop'>.priceproductname`

Should be: `50`

What i should use to do this?

Comment: shop = GameShop --> shop = GameShop()

Comment: @balderman Doesn't make a difference since `shop` isn't used anyway, and there are no instance attributes/methods so there's no reason to instantiate the class.

Comment: `getattr(GameShop, 'priceManaPotion')`

Comment: Why `itemy`, instead of just setting the class attributes directly? (`class GameShop: ManaPotion = 50; ...`, then `print(getattr(GameShop, product_name))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `itemy` dictionary:

```
product_name = input("Product Name")
print(f'{GameShop.itemy[product_name]}'
```

The dictionary is really the only part of the `GameShop` class that you need; I'd suggest not even making `GameShop` a class, and just making a dict that's the source of truth for the item names and prices:

```
shop_prices = {
    "ManaPotion": 50,
    "HealthPotion": 50,
    "StaminaPotion": 50,
}
```

Then you can print the prices with a loop like:

```
print("Shop prices:")
for item, price in shop_prices.items():
    print(f"\t{item}: {price}")
```

and look up the price for a given item in `shop_prices` by using the item's name as the key:

```
item = input("What do you want to buy?")
try:
    print(f"That'll be {shop_prices[item]} gold pieces, please.")
except KeyError:
    print(f"Sorry, {item} isn't in this shop.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you would still like to use the class, you can do

```
try:
   price=getattr(shop, f"price{product_name}")
   print(f"The cost of {product_name} is {price}")
except AttributeError:
   print("Sorry, this item is not available")
```

Remember that get_attr is not a method and takes in the object as the first parameter